# Is it possible to run xunit Test cases in Visual Studio Professional 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, xunit

I have tried out many options like installing NuGet Packages for X Unit Test Runner, cleaning the solution. But nothing worked. I had installed Unit Test generator for Visual Studio. I could be able to generate test methods using Nunit Framework in my Visual Studio. But in Test Explorer, no test results are displaying. Even no updates.

On the other hand, MSTest is working fine. The list of test methods I had generated is displaying in Test Explorer and able to run the tests.

So, is it possible to run xunit test methods in Visual Studio 2012
Professional Edition?

Comment: The NuGet runner should only works for VS2013 and above. You have to download an extension or simply use tools such as TestDriven.net.

Comment: Thanks Lex. But TestDriven Product is licensed. Do you know any free tools?

Comment: it is free for personal usage.

Comment: Hi Lex, I Could see that the test explorer displaying in VS2013 Professional. For time being, I have used that only. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: I have opened the code in VS 2013 and installed the Nuget Package "Install-Package xunit.runner.visualstudio" to run xunit. After I rebuild the solution, the test explorer starts displaying xunit test methods.